# Setting a GWT widget's id

Tags: java, gwt

I have a FlowPanel object on gwt application.

```
FlowPanel flowPanel = new FlowPanel();
flowPanel.add(new Button("Edit"));
flowPanel.add(new Button("Delete"));
flowPanel.getElement().setId("idOfFlow");
```

It gives me the following error:

```
flowPanel.getElement().setId("idOfFlow") = No such instance method:
 'void com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$.setId (java.lang.String)'
```

How can I set the Id of the `FlowPanel`?

Comment: AFAIK, you're setting it correctly

Comment: You example works fine in my case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am using GWT 2.4.0, this code works fine.

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.getElement().setId("panel-id");
```

or

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
DOM.setElementProperty(panel.getElement(), "id", "panel-id");
```