# Set GWT 'HTML' Object's id

Tags: gwt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting a GWT widget’s id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380765/setting-a-gwt-widgets-id)

I would like to add an 'id' to my GWT 'HTML' object to ensure that a particular style gets applied to it.

```
HTML obj;
```

How can I assign an id for this obj?

I couldn't figure it out based on this [Javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTML.html)

Thanks.

Comment: See the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380765/setting-a-gwt-widgets-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use object.getElement().setId()

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set an id. Simply add a CSS class name:

```
obj.setStyleName("myStyle");
```

or

```
obj.getElement().getStyle()...
```

and set any style you need directly.